# How to run multiple ajax at once while one of them still processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to hit 1 UploadMainData API and 1 CheckingProgress API
But When  checking the network process, ProgressChecking only return when UploadMainData is finish,

What I want is the progresschecking run in the interval for every 2000 ms while the mainupload is still on processing
Should I using async : true in mainupload ?
How to implement this multiple ajax call ?

```
$("#formInputUnggah").submit(function (e) {
    
    
    $("#submitFile").html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Load..").prop("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "${local_server}/ABCController/UploadMainData",
      data: new FormData(this),
      processData: !1,
      contentType: !1,
      cache: !1,
      dataType: "json",
      
      success: function (e) {
          
      console.log(e);
      }
    });
    myVar = setInterval(checkprog, 2000);  // this is the checkingprogress API using interval
   e.preventDefault();
  });

function checkprog() {
    console.log("masuk");
    $
    .ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        asyn: true,
        url: '${local_server}/ABCController/progressChecking',
        dataType: 'json',
        
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            
             var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
             
             result = (response.data.processed_data / response.data.total_data ) *100 ; 
             
               elem.style.width = result.toFixed(0) + "%"; 
                 elem.innerHTML = result.toFixed(0)  + "%"; 
                
                 if(result==100){
                        
                        clearInterval(myVar);
                         $.confirm({
                            title : response.status,
                            content : response.status,
                            buttons : {
                                ok : {
                                    isHidden : false, 
                                    keys : [ 'y' ],
                                    action : function() {
                                        elem.style.width = "0%"; 
                                         elem.innerHTML = ""; 
                                         $("#formInputUnggah")[0].reset();
                                            $("#submitFile").html("Unggah").prop("disabled", false);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }); 
                   
                        
                    }else if(response.status=="Error/Failed"){
                        elem.style.width = "0%"; 
                         elem.innerHTML = ""; 
                         $("#formInputUnggah")[0].reset();
                            $("#submitFile").html("Unggah").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
        }
    });
    
    }
```

Comment: You should *always* use `async:true` (or just don't include it to default to true).  Note, it's not `asyn:`

Comment: This looks like a configuration option on your *server* to only process one request at a time.

Comment: @freedomn-m  already fix it,  but process inside the interval not giving any return, it's waiting the main process finish

Comment: In theory, both should be running at the same time. How long does your file take to upload? If its less than 2 seconds, then the checkProg call via the interval wont have time to run. Try using a large file to test it...